# Rendered an animation, accidentally skipped frames, re-rendered but it’s now blank?

Tags: rendering

I rendered an animation and it was not the right resolution and I skipped frames. So, I decided to re-render it but it’s skips through the render frames very  quickly and it’s completely blank the whole time. How do I get it to render normally so I can save the animations?

I’m very new to blender and I’m on iMac.

Comment: I should have also said that I fixed the resolution and included all frames before I re-rendered

Comment: share the file so people can have a look and find out what is the problem

Comment: @Paul Is the _Overwrite_ option disabled in the _Output_ settings? In this case rendering will skip all frames that you've rendered before if you didn't change the name for the output files, no matter if you change resolution or any other render settings.